# How does the following code have a stack smashing error?

Tags: c

I wrote the following program to find the sum of the digits of an input number (`n`) which are less than the first digit of the number (`sumlessfirst(n)` function) or the sum of digits of the input number (`n`) which are less than a user-defined number(`x`) (`sumlessinput(n,x)` function). The user has to enter "first" to go for `sumlessfirst(n)` function or enter "custom" to go for `sumlessinput(n,x)`. But upon compiling, the code takes the input from the user for "first" or "custom" and then shows a stack smashing error. What are the reasons for this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sumlessfirst(int n)
{
    int i, j = n, sum = 0, sum1 = 0, count = 0;
    for (i = n; i > 0; i = i / 10)
    {
        count = count + 1;
    }
    while (count >= 2)
    {
        j = j / 10;
        count = count - 1;
    }
    int k;
    for (k = n; k > 0; k = k / 10)
    {
        if (k % 10 > j)
        {
            sum1 = sum1 + k % 10;
        }
    }
    printf("The sum of digits less than the first digit off %d is %d\n", n, sum1);
    return 0;
}

int sumlessinput(int n, int x)
{
    int i, sum;
    for (i = n; i > 0; i = i / 10)
    {
        if (i % 10 > x)
        {
            sum = sum + i % 10;
        }
    }
    printf("The sum of digits greater than %d of %d is %d\n", x, n, sum);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int n, x;
    char s[100];
    printf("Enter whether you want to go for the first digit or go for a custom value\n");
    printf("If you wanna go for first digit, enter first\n");
    printf("Tf you wanna go for custom input, enter custom\n");
    scanf("%s", &s[100]);
    if (s == "first" || s == "First")
    {
        printf("Enter the number: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        sumlessfirst(n);
    }
    else if (s == "custom" || s == "Custom")
    {
        printf("Enter the number: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("Enter the custom value: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        sumlessinput(n, x);
    }
}
```

The error that I get is:

```
Enter whether you want to go for the first digit or go for a custom value
If you wann go for first digit, enter first
If you wann go for custom input, enter custom
custom
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `scanf()`

```
int main()
{
     int n,x;
     char s[100];
     printf("Enter whether you want to go for the first digit or go for a custom value\n");
     printf("If you wanna go for first digit, enter first\n");
     printf("If you wanna go for custom input, enter custom\n");

     scanf("%s", &s[100]);     // <-- HERE
     if (s == "first" || s == "First")  //   <-- WRONG TOO
     {
         ...
```

Your code is calling `scanf()`, telling it to read a string into the 101st byte of variable `s`, which is only 100 bytes (index 0 -> 99) long.

This call should be:

```
scanf("%s", &s[0]);
```

Or just:

```
scanf("%s", s);
```

The next line is also not correct.  It's not valid to simply compare two strings like this.  This is because in `C`, strings resolve to a pointer, and this code becomes two pointer comparisons.  So regardless of what string-content the pointers may point at, the pointers themselves are different.

You are probably after the `strcmp()` function:

```
if (strcmp(s, "first") == 0)  # TODO handle capitalisation
{
    ...
```

Or alternatively, just check the first letter:

```
if ( s[0] == 'F' || s[0] == 'f' )
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass the Address of the one-past-the-end element of `s` to `scanf()`. You have to pass the address of the first element:

```
scanf("%s", s);
```

Furthermore, please NEVER use the conversion specifier `"%s"` without specifying a `width` to limit the number of characters that get written to the array to avoid a buffer overflow:

```
scanf("%99s", s);  // no more than 99 character + the terminating '\0'
```

---

As @Kingsley said, use `strcmp()` to compare two strings.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C have indexes from `zero` to `size - 1` so id you declare `type arr[100]` the element with index `100` is outside the array